# AWS API gateway pointing to Elastic : access key PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

We have a setup where in the front we have AWS API gateway which is internally pointing to Elastic application. The API gateway is secured with an access key.

I am looking for a way to send the API key using the Elastic php library. So far have looked the [Elastic PHP reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/ElasticsearchPHP_Endpoints.html) but have not found any solution.

I know we have to set the header as **x-api-key: value** in the request but do not find any information on how to set it using the Elastic PHP library.

Note :
The header x-api-key is successfully tested in postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution : thanks to Zachary Tong from elastic

```
$client_builder = ClientBuilder::create();
$client_builder->setConnectionParams([
  'headers' => [
    'x-api-key' => 'headerValue'
  ]
]);
```